# Does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument even though there is a constructor that takes 1 argument

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a class that will hold a row of data from a CSV file along with its header information.  Then outside the class I am making a List<> of elements of this class.  However I am getting this error which completely worthless,  "DynamicCSV does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments."  Fact is it does in fact contain a constructor with 1 argument.

```
class DynamicCSV : DynamicObject
{
    public List<string> columnHeaders;
    public List<string> rowData;

    /* Constructor with 1 argument */        
    DynamicCSV(List<string> headers)
    {
        columnHeaders = new List<string>();
        dynamic rowData = new List<string>();
        columnHeaders = headers;
    }
}


/* code that calls the constructor */
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    List<string> headers = new List<string>();
    List<string> dataRow = new List<string>();
    List<DynamicCSV> dataRows = new List<DynamicCSV>();

    if (true == isHeaderRow)
    {
        currentRow = streamReader.ReadLine();
        headers.AddRange(currentRow.Split(','));

        dataRows.Add(new DynamicCSV(headers));  // here is the error
        isHeaderRow = false;
    }

    else
    {
        currentRow = streamReader.ReadLine();
        dataRow.AddRange(currentRow.Split(','));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to mark the constructor as `public` (or possibly `internal`).

Comment: Wow Thanks!  That was amazing.  It only < 60 seconds to get an answer.  I'm an idiot, but thanks.

Comment: No worries, we all have moments like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make your contructor `public`, otherwise it can't be 'seen'.